# wordpress php targeting multiple ids to change colour

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay, so i've got a request for this update which I thought might be simple enough but is turing out a bit tricky than I though.

basically the site has these sub ids for each property 'Vest' and 'Verve' they want each one to be a different colour.

The css that's link to them is `<span class="proptery-type-grid">` so obviously I'd add in a second css for each colour, but the id's in the php are being called like this: `<span class="proptery-type-grid"<?php echo inspiry_get_property_types( $post->ID );?></span>`

so what would be the best way (i'm thinking like a if or else statement) to go about targeting the individual ids to change the colours of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with

```
<span class="proptery-type-grid"><?php $post_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property-type' );
     foreach( $post_terms as $term) {
  if( $term->name == 'Verve') {
    echo '<span class="proptery-verve">Verve</span>';
  } elseif( $term->name == 'Zest') {
    echo '<span class="proptery-zest">Zest</span>';
  } else {
    echo '<span class="proptery-type-grid type-none"></span>';
  }
}?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a ternary statement? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Psuedocode:

```
echo ($post->ID('1') ? '<span class="proptery-type-grid"<?php echo inspiry_get_property_types( $post->ID );?></span>' : '<?php echo inspiry_get_property_types( $post->ID );?>');
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with the slugs, because I don't know what the id for the categories would be, since it's using a sub post section. So the slugs would be verve and zest and they want verve to appear in orange and zest to appear in blue. So how will I add in two different classes in the php?

Comment: If it's using mysql, you can use something like `Select name, id from table where name = slug and id = int(x);` Once you pass that to some variables, you can start using that ternary on the fly with a while loop; on the other hand it looks like a regular if then statement might work better for you in this case without the ternary logic. (just to keep things simple for now)

Comment: Can you give an example of how I would write up such a if then statement, php is something i'm still trying to understand

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php has some good examples of mysqli. if you need to do more reading on the if statement syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php once you understand those, you can see how a switch statement makes things look better http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: the example you gave in pastebin.com/AwiyF1NC comes up with a couple of syntax errors when I tried it out